# Java: File is locked in application

Tags: java

In our program, we can import a jar or fxml file to use custom JavaFX components. Therefore the file is copied into a separate directory and the application only uses the copied file to process the scanning and so on.

In a few cases, it can happen, that for example the original jar was changed and it is rebuilt with maven with command "clean". So this would delete all necessary files, including the imported jar file. But if our application is still running, maven fails because the jar cannot be deleted. There seems to be a lock on the file, that prevent the jar from being deleted. Only if we close the application first, the jar can finally be deleted.

So is there any way to release the file, so that it doesn't interrupt any action on the file, even if the application is running?

Deleting the file already fails before the file is copied.

**EDIT**

Ok, the hint with the scanning process was correct I think. Before the jar is copied, the program scans the original jar to find the components that should be included. The file is locked right after a JarFile object is created.

```
public JarReport explore(ClassLoader classLoader) throws IOException {
    final JarReport result = new JarReport(jar);
    
    try (JarFile jarFile = new JarFile(jar.toFile())) {
        final Enumeration<JarEntry> e = jarFile.entries();
        while (e.hasMoreElements()) {
            final JarEntry entry = e.nextElement();
            result.getEntries().add(exploreEntry(entry, classLoader));
        }
    }
    
    return result;
}
```

So in line 4, the JarFile object is created, which means the file was unzipped. Right after this line, I cannot delete the jar anymore. So do I have to close the unzipped file before I can delete it?

Comment: Please add some more information about your scanning process. Probably you forgot to close something in there

Answer (score 0):

If what you want is to stop erasing the file [then read the documentation here](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/examples/include-exclude.html), if what you want is to ensure that the file is erased, then make sure there are NO refferences to the file, nor using any file related operations on the given file...

If you are using Windows, then if an application has control over a file (for instance a `C` program, has `File`.`fopen( x )`, then X cannot be accessed from another application, nor writte (and delete starts by writting).

In linux, there is the `rm` command that will erase the file, even if an application currently holds the file resource

Answer (score 0):

On Windows, [SysInternals Handle](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896655) can close handles (`-c`) of files that are in use. It's a command line tool that can run without user interaction.

> -c    Closes the specified handle (interpreted as a hexadecimal number). You must specify the process by its PID.
>   WARNING: Closing handles can cause application or system instability.

It may be necessary to write a small batch script that first searches the handle by file name and then closes it.